# Why metadata is not valid "token_uri": null

Tags: solidity, meta-data

I've been testing a smart contract using remix with validated metadata that I have used in one of the NFT smart contracts that I deployed on mainnet and everything worked well, but this time when used & deployed the same smart contract with the same metadata structure (using remix), I couldn't see the NFTs that I minted on opensea Testnet.

```
ipfs://QmNzcydNR1Hh75g8C9FBvhVZe8fiRQJ9YkGwsgvgrRQBQj/eth.json
```

I've used **https://rinkeby-api.opensea.io/** to debug my metadata

I got the error bellow

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "valid": true,
    "token_uri": null,
    "errors": []
}
```

Comment: not an answer but I confirm that the cid `QmNzcydNR1Hh75g8C9FBvhVZe8fiRQJ9YkGwsgvgrRQBQj` has data https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmNzcydNR1Hh75g8C9FBvhVZe8fiRQJ9YkGwsgvgrRQBQj/eth.json

Comment: Yeah, That's why I got confused! still can't see the NFT on opensea showing

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem at https://testnets-api.opensea.io/asset/0x53ebb882e54bad1a97a8c69c9a9880ce2d101ec0/1/validate/

Comment: I also have similar issues. Does anyone figure out what is the reason?

Comment: I have the same problem. Looks like an OpenSea problem. Rarible displays everything fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem, while the data is correct, it is getting a "token_uri" : null
https://testnets-api.opensea.io/asset/0x2D8aC58b1957c5cb4A6158dBC9343dA0fE13f51f/0/validate

The token is showing fine in rarible testnet, but not on OS.  It may be an OpenSea problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem in last 5 days.
Opensea is not showing any metadata

Rarible is showing the metadata ok.

I had wrote message to Opensea support and waiting the reply.

regard
tomas

this is my metadata url https://cryptotest1.s3.amazonaws.com/a/1.json

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is removing the file extension from the files so the ipfs url reference didn't have the .json file extension a the end and nor did the tokenURI.

Hope this helps everyone

Comment: This is the right answer. It worked for me, thanks